# Stacking divs vertically

Tags: css, html

I'm programming a tic-tac-toe game and having trouble stacking my game tiles vertically to be  3x3 box.

As it stands, they are 9 horizontal boxes in a row, but when I use {clear: left;} It just turns them into 9 vertical boxes.

Here's my code so far:

```
<style type="text/css">
#div1 {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    float:left;

}
#div2 {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    float:left;
}
#div3 {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    float:left;
}
<body>
    <p>Drag the X and O images into the tic-tac-toe board:</p>
    <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

    <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

    <div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Consider using `display: table`, `display: table-row` and `display: table-cell`, since it seems you basically want to create a grid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/justjavac/9s8CX/

```
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
```

CSS

```
#div1 {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    float:left;
    clear: left;
}
#div2 {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    float:left;    // <---- HERE
}
#div3 {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not just create a `parent` element, such as `#parent`, and set a defined width on it? Doing this, you don't have to change the position of the elements in the DOM.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/hL6e7/)

```
#parent {
    width: 306px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Alternatively, you could also create `row` elements, as parents of each of the 3 child elements, and set `display:block`. In doing so, you could have to set an explicit width on the parent.. works well for dynamic content, or responsive design..

---

On a random note, I thought it would be cool to add something like:

```
#parent:hover > div:not(:hover){
    background:black;
}
```

Basically, this sets the `background-color` of the children elements to black when hovering over the parent. However, when hovering over the child, it specifically isn't applied.. try hovering over the tiles.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/hL6e7/)

Answer (score 1):

First off, make sure you close your `style` tag.

You don't need to repeat your styles for each row (since it is exactly the same for `div1`, `div2` and `div3`), instead change the `ID` to a `class` because IDs are intended for a single element.

To create rows you will need to place the 3 DIVs you want in a row inside another `DIV` with the `position:relative` attribute.

CSS:

```
.mydiv {
    wclassth: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solclass #aaaaaa;
    float:left;
}

.myrow {
    position:relative;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="myrow">
    <div class="mydiv" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div class="mydiv" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div class="mydiv" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
</div>
<div class="myrow">
    <div class="mydiv" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div class="mydiv" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div class="mydiv" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
</div>
<div class="myrow">
    <div class="mydiv" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div class="mydiv" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div class="mydiv" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J2Qjb/

Please note that I added a background color to the mydiv class on the JSFiddle so that it would be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution using `display: inline-block;` and some br tags:

http://jsfiddle.net/jWe9K/